# Remove string except in specified fields

Tags: r, regex, str-replace, gsub

I hope to use str_replace or gsub to remove the characters " WD " and replace it with " " from within a column in my dataframe. However, there are certain fields within the column that I do not want the " WD " characters to be removed. Note, there are over 8,000 features in the data I am processing, so a line of code without the requirement of typing every field string I would like to change is essential.

```
df = PA_prec

COLUMN

PA CRAWFORD MEADVILLE WD 02

PA CRAWFORD TITUSVILLE WD 02

PA BLAIR HOLLIDAYSBURG WD 01

PA BLAIR ALTOONA WD 03
```

**GOAL: I want all " WD " characters removed except in PA CRAWFORD TITUSVILLE and PA BLAIR HOLLIDAYSBURG.**

The code should look something like:

```
PA_prec$COLUMN <- str_replace(PA_prec$COLUMN, " WD ", " ")
```

or

```
PA_prec$COLUMN <- gsub("\\.", "", PA_prec$COLUMN)
```

...but I need to exclude the two fields listed above.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sub("(?<!TITUSVILLE |HOLLIDAYSBURG )WD ", "", x, perl = T)
```

Here we use negative lookbehind, which can be glossed as "match if you do not see ... on the left". Note: this only works with `sub` if you use `perl = T`.

Comment: Wonderful! This seemed to work. However, do you know if I can identify WD as " WD " so that I can ensure that I am only removing the character WD where there is a space in the front and the back? I tried adding a space to the front and back of WD in the code you sent and it didn't work. Thanks :)

Comment: Please see edited solution: this now removes `WD`without leaving any redundant whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(?<!TITUSVILLE|HOLLIDAYSBURG)\sWD\s
```

See [poof](https://regex101.com/r/1v6T2C/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TITUSVILLE               'TITUSVILLE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    HOLLIDAYSBURG            'HOLLIDAYSBURG'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  WD                       'WD'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
```

[R code](http://%3Ca%20href=%22https://tio.run/##K/r/PyVNwUZXISWxJFEvrSgxN1XD2d8n1NfPNllDKcBRwTnIMdzNP8hFwdfV0SXM08fHVSHcRcHASEkHRTbEMyQ0GEPaycfRM0jBw9/Hx9PFMTLYKTTIHSxtiCzt6BPi7@/nCJYwVtLU5EpJU4E4AeSu4tIkDSUNextFhA01KAZqxsQUh7sACSUdBSUFIAHXrqNQkFqUYxsSFOoKMvT/fwA%22%20title=%22R%20%E2%80%93%20Try%20It%20Online%22%3ETry%20it%20online!%3C/a%3E):

```
df <- data.frame(COLUMN=c("PA CRAWFORD MEADVILLE WD 02","PA CRAWFORD TITUSVILLE WD 02","PA BLAIR HOLLIDAYSBURG WD 01","PA BLAIR ALTOONA WD 03"))
df$COLUMN <- sub("(?<!TITUSVILLE|HOLLIDAYSBURG)\\sWD\\s", " ", df$COLUMN, perl=TRUE)
df
```

Output:

```
                        COLUMN
1     PA CRAWFORD MEADVILLE 02
2 PA CRAWFORD TITUSVILLE WD 02
3 PA BLAIR HOLLIDAYSBURG WD 01
4          PA BLAIR ALTOONA 03
```